# How to display bars for 0 value in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to show the value of a result even when zero or close to zero, however I can't get the plot to show the values. How do I get matplotlib to show the bar for these cases? I have tried adjusting the bottom of the plot so that it might show zero values, however the length of the bars is still zero.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

results = [0.7, 0, 0.8, 0.85, 0.6]

n_groups = 5
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.25
opacity = 0.8
plt.ylim(top=1.05,bottom=-0.01)

rects1 = plt.bar(index, results, bar_width,
alpha=opacity,
bottom=-0.1)

plt.xlabel('Algorithm')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('Model Comparison')
plt.xticks(index, ('SVM', 'KNN', 'DT', 'RF', 'oSVC'))
plt.show()
```

[Plot from example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctbzi.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you considered adding the values as labels on the top of the bar ? Please check the examples from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html).

Comment: Yes, I have considered this. The problem becomes that for my graphs there will be up to 64 bars on one graph. So adding text for the values doesn't look good and ends up being a bit cramped.

Comment: Matplotlib won't show any bar with 0 height and I think it makes sense. However, I understand that if you have value like 0.001, it won't also show up. Am I getting it right?

Comment: I have reduced the bottom of my graph to -0.01, the idea was to allow Matplotlib to graph the bars with a value of zero since that should give them a length of 0.01. However, the bars still don't show up on the bar graph.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib won't show bar which has zero height because *it does not have any height*. However, if there are bars with height order of magnitude lesser than others bars in the data, [changing the scale of Y-axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html) would help.

For example, using symmetric log axis scaling, we can get:
[image]

Code to reproduce the figure above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

results = [0.7, 0, 0.8, 0.85, 0.006, 1.0]

n_groups = 6
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.25
opacity = 0.8

rects1 = plt.bar(index, results, bar_width, alpha=opacity)

yticks = [i for i in results if i!=0.0]

plt.yscale("symlog")
plt.gca().set_yticks(yticks)
plt.ylim(bottom=-.1)

for k in yticks:    
    plt.gca().axhline(k, lw=0.1, color='black', ls=":")

plt.gca().axhline(0, lw=0.3, color='red', label="Zero accuracy")
plt.xlabel('Algorithm')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('Model Comparison')
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(index, ('SVM', "KNN", 'DT', 'RF', 'oSVC', "Random"))
plt.show()
```